# How to multiply a canvases when saving and printing?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, fabricjs

I would like to save and print my canvas "multiplied" so that the final result is an image 4 canvases wide and 2 canvases tall. I'm wondering if it is possible to either:

- "multiply" the canvas 4 wide and 2 tall so that the result
- have canvas be the size of 4 x 2 of the original canvas but only have a portion that is the size of the original canvas be editable, then that portion be "copied/mirrored" to the rest of the canvas so that it creates 8 total images.
- etc; maybe you will have a brighter method to achieving this; **basically I want to be able to "edit" once for 8 of the same image**.

**Why?**

I tried scaling my canvas in my print dialog when I'd go to print it but I was only able to get it to print more than 6 or less than 9 per page. I also figure having one solid image would be cleaner.

**Visuals**

Here's what I'd like to save and print for:

[image]

**Code**

```js
var activeCanvas, front, back, canvas1, canvas2;
$(document).ready(function() {

  canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('front');
  canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('back');
  canvas1.setHeight(360);
  canvas1.setWidth(208);
  canvas2.setHeight(360);
  canvas2.setWidth(208);
  changeView(1);

  var padding = 20;
  canvas1.on('object:moving', onObjectMoving);
  canvas2.on('object:moving', onObjectMoving);

  function onObjectMoving(e) {
    var obj = e.target;

    // if object is too big ignore
    if (obj.currentHeight > obj.canvas.height - padding * 2 ||
      obj.currentWidth > obj.canvas.width - padding * 2) {
      return;
    }
    obj.setCoords();

    // top-left corner
    if (obj.getBoundingRect().top < padding ||
      obj.getBoundingRect().left < padding) {
      obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top - obj.getBoundingRect().top + padding);
      obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left - obj.getBoundingRect().left + padding);
    }

    // bot-right corner
    if (obj.getBoundingRect().top + obj.getBoundingRect().height > obj.canvas.height - padding ||
      obj.getBoundingRect().left + obj.getBoundingRect().width > obj.canvas.width - padding) {
      obj.top = Math.min(
        obj.top,
        obj.canvas.height - obj.getBoundingRect().height + obj.top - obj.getBoundingRect().top - padding);
      obj.left = Math.min(
        obj.left,
        obj.canvas.width - obj.getBoundingRect().width + obj.left - obj.getBoundingRect().left - padding);
    }
  };
});

function changeView(value) {
  if (value == 1) {
    activeCanvas = canvas1;
    $('#front').parent().css('display', 'block');
    $('#back').parent().css('display', 'none');
  }

  if (value == 2) {
    activeCanvas = canvas2;
    $('#front').parent().css('display', 'none');
    $('#back').parent().css('display', 'block');
  }
}

// Add Text 
function dropText() {
  var text = new fabric.Text('Hello', {
    top: 20,
    left: 20,
  });
  activeCanvas.add(text);
}

// Save
function download(url, name) {
  // make the link. set the href and download. emulate dom click
  $('<a>').attr({
    href: url,
    download: name
  })[0].click();
}

function downloadFabric(canvas, name) {
  //  convert the canvas to a data url and download it.
  download(activeCanvas.toDataURL({
    multiplier: 2
  }), name + '.png');
}

// Print
function printCanvas() {
  var dataUrl = document.getElementById('activeCanvas').toDataURL();
  var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
  windowContent += '<html>'
  windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
  windowContent += '<body>'
  windowContent += '<img src="' + dataUrl + '" onload=window.print();window.close();>';
  windowContent += '</body>';
  windowContent += '</html>';
  var printWin = window.open('', '', 'width=340,height=260');
  printWin.document.open();
  printWin.document.write(windowContent);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeView(1);">Front</button>
<button onclick="changeView(2);">Back</button>
<button onclick="dropText();">Add Text</button>
<button onclick="downloadFabric()">Save</button>
<button onclick="">Print</button>

<div style="text-align: center">
  <canvas id="front"></canvas>
  <canvas id="back"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide a picture exemplifying what is the result expected

Comment: Definitely, will edit!

Comment: I re-thought out my question and rewrote it in an attempt to be clearer. I also included a photo of what I'm trying to save for and print on.

Comment: And what about front and back sides? Must they be printed together at the one side of the paper (so you have to multiply each side 4 times)? Or maybe you want to print only one side of a canvas on the one side of the paper (so you have to multiply each side 8 times)?

Comment: @Sam Ideally, the latter so that each side fits each side of the paper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to create a grid of 4x2 canvases, with all but the first being invisible initially. Then when you are about to print, clone the canvas - you can convert a canvas to JSON as follows:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(canvas);
```

And then load that JSON into as many canvases as you wish:

```
canvas2.loadFromJSON(json);
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/whippet71/q54k4vww/4/) a very simple fiddle. You'll need a bit of extra CSS to get the layout of your canvases right.

Comment: This looks interesting! Once I have all of the canvases though where should I go from there? Am I able to somehow combine these?

Comment: So initially only one canvas would be visible and that's where you edit your image. Then when you're about to print, copy the contents onto the other canvases, then you should have 8 identical copies of your image on screen in a 4x2 grid, and if you print so that the page layout is set to landscape and scaled to fit your paper you'll get the desired result.

Comment: @JohnM could one print the same canvas N times (changing the text objects for each of them) with this method ? Each canvas need to occupy 1 page for print.

Comment: @emre-ozgun Sure I don't see why not, you would need to do a regexp replace on the JSON string to change the text, which could be a little bit messy. Then just make sure that your CSS sets the break-after property on each canvas.

Comment: @JohnM thanks for the response John, I just learned about break-after property to append content AS new page on the document to be printed. Why did you suggest regexp replacement on JSON ? Can't I just loop over N times (data.length times), generate an innerHTML wrapper (to be targeted via print media query) generate the document append all the sub-html with canvas and just print all of them at once ? Is there any resource you can direct me to that tackles this problem ?

Comment: @emre-ozgun I wasn't sure how you would be generating the text for each canvas or how many differences there would be between them, but it sounds like your approach could work too - it's a bit difficult to visualize without an example

Comment: @JohnM Hey John!, Mind helping ? I'm struggling to print multiple canvases.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74099956/fabricjs-canvas-converting-multiple-fabricjs-canvases-to-images-via-loop-a

Answer (score 1):

push Run code snippet!

**you should generate something similar and to work more on css for printing
note this code isn't a final code you can use in production you need to put css values correctly for printing**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
<style type="text/css">

.rTable {
       display: table;
       width: 100%;/* =208*4 */
  }
  .rTableRow {
       display: table-row;
  }
  .rTableHeading {
       display: table-header-group;
       background-color: #ddd;
  }
  .rTableCell, .rTableHead {
       display: table-cell;
       padding: 3px 10px;
       border: 1px solid #999999;
    width:208pt;/*use values in pt !*/
     height:360pt;
  }
  .rTableHeading {
       display: table-header-group;
       background-color: #ddd;
       font-weight: bold;
  }
  .rTableFoot {
       display: table-footer-group;
       font-weight: bold;
       background-color: #ddd;
  }
  .rTableBody {
       display: table-row-group;
  }
  body{
   margin:0;
  }  
  </style>
  <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body >
  
 <!-- <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script> 
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script> -->

     <div class="rTable">
     <div class="rTableRow">
      <div class="rTableRow">
       <div class="rTableCell"><canvas id="front"></canvas><canvas id="back"></canvas></div>
       <div class="rTableCell"><canvas id="front"></canvas><canvas id="back"></canvas></div>
       <div class="rTableCell"><canvas id="front"></canvas><canvas id="back"></canvas></div>
       <div class="rTableCell"><canvas id="front"></canvas><canvas id="back"></canvas></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rTableRow">
       <div class="rTableCell"><canvas id="front"></canvas><canvas id="back"></canvas></div>
       <div class="rTableCell"><canvas id="front"></canvas><canvas id="back"></canvas></div>
       <div class="rTableCell"><canvas id="front"></canvas><canvas id="back"></canvas></div>
       <div class="rTableCell"><canvas id="front"></canvas><canvas id="back"></canvas></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--

  

$('canvas#back').each(function(index) {
    //console.log(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
 context=$(this).get(0).getContext('2d');

 context.font = 'italic 20pt Calibri';
 context.fillText('Hello!', 20, 20);
});



//-->
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: p.s.  Also combining this  with @John M 's sample you get more precise

Comment: Hi, yes that looks like the route I'm going to try. Thank you for adding this @Constantin. I appreciate it!