# fabric.js - React.js - canvas - Printing multiple fabric canvases that contain images (w/ react-to-print)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, printing, fabricjs

So I'm trying to document print multiple fabric images. Here is the preparation process. I see a blank window. I can provide additional information on request. Some sort of async logic I'm missing out maybe ?

1- I initialize a canvas from each canvas object (looping over an array of canvases - each canvas object has an image and possibly multiple textbox objects)

2- I then use toDataURL() and create image element for each, attach the src to img

3- I loop over the images and append them to printWindow.

```
   const handleCustomPrint = () => {

    const div = document.querySelector('.print-content');

    for (let i = 0; i < canvasArrayToBePrinted.length; i++) {
      const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(`${i}`)
      canvas.loadFromJSON(canvasArrayToBePrinted[i], () => {
        const img = canvas.toDataURL({
          format: 'jpeg',
          quality: 0.75
        });
        const singleImg = `<img src=${img} class='image-content' />`
        div.innerHTML += singleImg;
      });
    }

    console.log(div);

    var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
    var uniqueName = new Date();
    var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
    var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=50000,top=50000,width=1000000,height=10000');
    printWindow.document.write(div.innerHTML);

    printWindow.document.close();

    printWindow.onload = function() {
      printWindow.focus();
      printWindow.print();
      printWindow.close();
    }
    return true;

  };
```

EDIT: OK. I think I'm getting close. But still can't see nothing.

This is the output of console.log(div)

```
<div class="print-content">
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ..." class="img-content"/>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ..." class="img-content"/>
</div>
```

This is the CSS for targeting print styles

```
@media all {
  .img-content {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .print-content {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media print {

  .print-content {
    display: block !important;
  }

  .img-print {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it is a problem with the images. Does it work if you only include the textboxes?

Comment: @JohnM You mean by omitting toDataURL(). And removing image object from canvases ?

Comment: I mean just removing any image objects from the canvases

Comment: @JohnM  I resolved the issue with a different approach, with the help of react-to-print (which allowed me to print react components) - That image conversion turned out to be useless. I'm looping over the canvas array, create canvas for each data in the loop and then fire document.print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preparing canvases (loadFromJSON callback is the indicator that indicates whether the canvas is initialized with all its objects (images/textboxes) attached to it... )

```
const PrintContent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {

  const { canvasData, setIsPrintReady, shouldExcludeImage } = props;

  const [preparedCanvases, setPreparedCanvases] = React.useState({ prepared: 0, total: canvasData.length });

  const incrementPrepared = () => setPreparedCanvases(prev => ({ ...prev, prepared: prev.prepared + 1 }));

  const imageToBePrinted = canvasData && canvasData.length && canvasData[0].objects.find(o => o.type === 'image');

  const { width, height } = imageToBePrinted;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (preparedCanvases.prepared === preparedCanvases.total) {
      setIsPrintReady(true);
    }
  }, [preparedCanvases, setIsPrintReady])

  return (
    <div className="content-to-be-printed" ref={ref}>
      {
        props.canvasData && props.canvasData.length && props.canvasData.map((singleCanvas, idx) => {
          return <SingleCanvasData
            key={`${idx}--canvas`}
            singleCanvas={singleCanvas}
            index={idx}
            incrementPrepared={incrementPrepared}
            imgWidth={width}
            imgHeight={height}
            shouldExcludeImage={shouldExcludeImage}
            />
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
});
```

```
const SingleCanvasData = ({ singleCanvas, index, incrementPrepared, imgWidth, imgHeight, shouldExcludeImage }) => {

  const [canvas, setCanvas] = React.useState("");
  const [once, setOnce] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const initCanvas = () =>
      new fabric.Canvas(`${index}`, {
        height: imgHeight,
        width: imgWidth,
        preserveObjectStacking: true
      });
    setCanvas(initCanvas());
  }, [index, imgHeight, imgWidth]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (once && canvas) {

      let canvasWithoutImage;
      if(!shouldExcludeImage) {
        canvasWithoutImage = {...singleCanvas, objects: singleCanvas.objects.filter(o => o.type !== 'image')};
      }

      canvas.loadFromJSON(canvasWithoutImage || singleCanvas, () => {
        incrementPrepared();
      });
      setOnce(false);
    }

  }, [canvas, incrementPrepared, once, singleCanvas, shouldExcludeImage]);

  return (
    <canvas
      style={{ width: 'auto', height: 'auto' }}
      className="single-canvas"
      id={index}
      key={`canvas-${index}`}>

    </canvas>
  )
}

export default PrintContent
```

Parent

```
      {
        canPrint && (
          <PrintContent
            canvasData={canvasArrayToBePrinted}
            setIsPrintReady={setIsPrintReady}
            ref={componentRef}
            shouldExcludeImage={shouldExcludeImage} />
        )
      }
```

useReactToPrint hook (attach ref to the component you want to print (in my case its forwardRef because I'm passing ref down to a component) - you can also declare print styles via props - super nifty) that allows you to print a  react component (react-to-print)

```
  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    pageStyle: `
    @page { size: ${pageSize.widthPX}px ${pageSize.heightPX}px; margin: 0mm; }
    `,
    content: () => componentRef.current,
    onAfterPrint: () => handleResetPrintModal()
  });
```

Enable print button when print is ready

```
            <button disabled={!isPrintReady || !pageSize.widthPX}
              onClick={handlePrint}
              className='btn-primary btn-success'>
              Print
            </button>
```